# Accounting for a typical order/orderLine DDD implementation . How to get total product sales?

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design

Assuming a typical model for the orders :

Order (aggregateRoot) {OrderLine}
OrderLine (entityInsideOrderAR) {Product;quantity}
Product(aggregateRoot) {name}

Is that a proper design for accounting purpose ? I mean , where should calculateTotalProductSales() reside ? The reference should be acyclic so if product shoud have an OrderCollection this would not be a good design . Even for a special aggregate child of Product , ProductHistory should reference Order and again there is one object loaded multiple times (cyclic reference) .

What would be a good design for this case ? Basically i need to do some calculations based on product sales (countTotalSalesForProduct(), calculateTotalSalesForProduct() etc... some simple accounting calculations).

P.S. : Is it a good ideea to move OrderLine up one level and make it an AR of it's own ?

Answer (score 2):

One could split accounting functionalities into a sperate bounded context. A set of exclusive models could be developed without breaking existing ordering context. Besides, there are a lot of order information are not necessary for accounting domain in reality(e.g. shipping address, remark and so on). Reports and statistics are also common requirements in accounting domain which make the one-size-fits-all domain model solution worse. They may be implemented as complex SQL which is hard to test and maintain or cause domain logic leak into infrastructure layer.

Using domain events to integrate the two bounded context maybe a good idea. You could refer to [Accounting Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accounting.pdf), in which Martin Fowler suggests using events to trigger accounting processes.

Comment: I don't see why i should not break the ordering  if accounting for a product i striclty tied to the Product itself (a product history). Using only sql would mean to move the logic outside the domain which is not a good ideea . Accounting for a product is tied to the product itself (it's sales hisotory) and i don't see why it should be moved to another context , it relies on this aggregate root .

Comment: @GeoC. The product is a business concept and could be mapped to different domain models (or even not ddd based) in different bounded context. Different bounded context have different requirments which makes it too hard to develop a generic domain model.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look into [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) pattern for this. You're using domain objects in two ways. You can't get all the Product sales unless you fetch all the Orders from the database and traverse them in some loop. That would be, well, slow. That's why reporting is usually done in another bounded context, as Hippoom suggested. Have a read.